# Flask and Werkzeug: Testing a post request with custom headers

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

I'm currently testing my app with suggestions from http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/testing/, but I would like to add a header to a post request.

My request is currently:

```
self.app.post('/v0/scenes/test/foo', data=dict(image=(StringIO('fake image'), 'image.png')))
```

but I would like to add a content-md5 to the request. Is this possible?

**My investigations:**

Flask Client (in flask/testing.py) extends Werkzeug's Client, documented here:
http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/test/

As you can see, `post` uses `open`. But `open` only has:

```
Parameters: 
 as_tuple – Returns a tuple in the form (environ, result)
 buffered – Set this to True to buffer the application run. This will automatically close the application for you as well.
 follow_redirects – Set this to True if the Client should follow HTTP redirects.
```

So it looks like it's not supported. How might I get such a feature working, though?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

`open` also take `*args` and `**kwargs` which used as `EnvironBuilder` arguments. So you can add just `headers` argument to your first post request:

```
with self.app.test_client() as client:
    client.post('/v0/scenes/test/foo',
                data=dict(image=(StringIO('fake image'), 'image.png')),
                headers={'content-md5': 'some hash'});
```

Answer (score 10):

Werkzeug to the rescue!

```
from werkzeug.test import EnvironBuilder, run_wsgi_app

builder = EnvironBuilder(path='/v0/scenes/bucket/foo', method='POST', data={'image': (StringIO('fake image'), 'image.png')}, \
    headers={'content-md5': 'some hash'})
env = builder.get_environ()

(app_iter, status, headers) = run_wsgi_app(http.app.wsgi_app, env)
status = int(status[:3]) # output will be something like 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
```

Comment: Why the extraneous import of Request?