# how to specify headers in python Flask while testing Flask application using flask.app.test_client()?

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, flask-testing

We are testing a Python Flask application using `flask.app.test_client` like explained [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/testing/)
Our application works with JWT tokens for authentication purpose, so all API call's must have the token specified. Is there way to provide JWT as header to `app.tests_client` ?
Below is the testing code snippet,

```
from app import app   # our flask application
import unittest
class AppTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app = app.app.test_client()
    def tearDown(self):
        pass
    def test_info_page(self):
        info_rs = self.app.get('/info')  ## --> this request should go with header JWT token.
        self.assertEqual(info_rs.status_code, 200)
```

Comment: Is this what you want? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25860304/how-do-i-set-response-headers-in-flask .

Comment: If you want to add headers to the request itself, you can use this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18266224/3872976

Comment: yes @deathangel908 , this is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18263844/flask-and-werkzeug-testing-a-post-request-with-custom-headers/18266224#18266224 what i was looking for, Thanks.